# Freeze CSS Animation using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, webkit, css-animations, keyframe

When I stop my animation it resets to the start state (0 zero degrees)  how do one pause it in its current rotation point? Stop and Start work fine.

```
function animFeeze(){
    //// what goes here?
}
function animStart(){
    // @-webkit-keyframes spinY {
    // from { transform: rotateY(0); }
    // to   { transform: rotateY(360deg); }
    document.getElementById("anim").style.WebkitAnimationName = "spinY";
}
function animStop(){
    // @-webkit-keyframes noAnim {}
    // @keyframes noAnim {}
    document.getElementById("anim").style.WebkitAnimationName = "noAnim";
}
function init() {

    animatePause.addEventListener("click", animFreeze, false);
    animateStart.addEventListener("click", animStart, false);
    animateStop.addEventListener("click", animStop, false);
    console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
}
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init, false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
document.getElementById("anim").style.animationPlayState="paused";
```

Set it to "running" to resume.

[Example JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zrr9ctky/)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you here is a pause toggle function that worked

```
function animPauseToggle(){
    var e = document.getElementById("anim");
    if(e.style.webkitAnimationPlayState == "paused") 
        e.style.webkitAnimationPlayState = "running";
    else
        e.style.webkitAnimationPlayState = "paused";
}
```

Comment: sure how do I do that?

Comment: very helpful thank you for your attention on the matter